# ¿como se puede hacer para que cuando al darle click a un icono de un menu este cambie a otro icono?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

ESTE ES EL XML

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     tools:context="org.sfaci.agenda.MainActivity">


 <item android:id="@+id/action_modificar"
     android:title="@string/action_settings"
     android:orderInCategory="100"
     android:showAsAction="ifRoom|never"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit" />

 <item android:id="@+id/action_GuardarDato"
     android:title="@string/action_settings"
     android:orderInCategory="100"
     android:showAsAction="ifRoom|never"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_check" /> </menu>
```

ESTE EL JAVA

```
 @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
         // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
         // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
         int id = item.getItemId();

         //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
         if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
             return true;
         }
         if (id == R.id.action_modificar){
            if (tvNombreApellidos.isEnabled()&& ivFoto.isEnabled()&&
             tvEmail.isEnabled()&& tvTelefonoFijo.isEnabled()&& tvTelefonoMovil.isEnabled()){
                 tvNombreApellidos.setEnabled(false);
                 ivFoto.setEnabled(false);
                 tvEmail.setEnabled(false);
                 tvTelefonoFijo.setEnabled(false);
                 tvTelefonoMovil.setEnabled(false);
             }else{
                 tvNombreApellidos.setEnabled(true);
                 ivFoto.setEnabled(true);
                 tvEmail.setEnabled(true);
                tvTelefonoFijo.setEnabled(true);
                 tvTelefonoMovil.setEnabled(true);
             }
         }

         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
```

Comment: A ver si entendi. Quieres cambiar el icono del menu o el texto del menu?

Comment: Tu vista es un Activity o un fragment? `menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.icono);`

Comment: cambiar el icono al hacer click en el que me ponga el otro y desaparexca el que estaba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes crear una variable de menú global e inicializarla en `onCreateOptionsMenu ()` y luego usarla en su `onClick ().` o en algun item de tu menú.

```
private Menu menu;
```

**En su onCreateOptionsMenu ()**

```
this.menu = menu;
```

**En el método onClick () de tu botón**

```
menu.getItem(0).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

> Nota: Los iconos se almacenan en la carpeta `mimap` y las imágenes en
>   la carpeta `drawable`. ¿Por que? A san google se le ocurrio separar
>   estos componentes, por orden he de suponer, y por ultimo asegúrate de
>   que tu icono o imagen contenga las 5 densidades para que no se vea
>   "borroso o distorsionado tu icono", como en la siguiente imagen :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ultimo dato, Google tiene una pagina donde puedes descargar iconos material desing ([ir a la pagina](https://material.io/icons/)) o puedes crear tu propio icono a partir de una imagen que quieras en esta [pagina](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/).

Comment: gracias Ashley me ha servido ,,

Comment: @alvin me alegro, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo mediante una variable

`boolean cambioImagen= false`

al dar clic al botón puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
if(cambioImagen==false){
  /*Código que cambie la imagen*/
  ...
 //Cambias el valor de la variable
 cambioImagen=true;
}else {
/*Código que cambie la imagen al estado original*/
//Vuelves a poner la variable a su estado original
cambioImagen=false;
}
```

Básicamente esa seria la idea, espero y te funcione.

**Nota:** Se podría decir que es la misma función de un toggle button.